# to remove the last few components in list with python

Tags: python

```
a=[3,2,2,3]
a.sort()
a.pop(a[3])
print(a)
a.pop(a[2])
print(a)
```

I want to delete the last two element in list `a` after sorting, but I get this error:

```
  [2, 2, 3]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:/Project/8.py", line 5, in <module>
    a.pop(a[2])
  IndexError: pop index out of range
```

Comment: You are not using `pop` correctly: if you give it an argument, it should be the index that you want to pop, not the value you want to pop (and `a[3]` gives the value at the index 3, when what you really want is just the index 3). See the answers bellow for a working code.

Comment: oh. thanks for helping!

Comment: 7 answers for a trivial Python question and no upvote for the question itself?

Answer (score 4):

`pop(i)` pops the element at index `i` in the list. When you do `a.pop(a[3])`, you're popping the element at index `a[3]=3`. If you want to pop the last element, just do `a.pop()` without any argument, it will implicitly pop the last element.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting the error is because you're looking up what index to pop by retrieving an integer from the list, so by doing `a[2]`, you are first fetching the value `3` and obviously this is outside of the range of the list.

So as said otherwise, just call `pop` without the parameter - `pop()`

Answer (score 2):

Simply make the list equal to itself minus the last two elements.

```
a=[3,2,2,3]
a.sort()
a=a[:-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `pop` is able to just remove the last element, you don't need to specify the argument.
Removing the sorting as it doesn't change much here you get:

```
a=[2,2,3,3]
a.pop()
print(a)
a.pop()
print(a)
```

It should do what you probably wanted.

**More context and explanation**

As [explained in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) if you optionally specify the parameter to `pop` - it takes in the index of the element to be removed.
So in yet even more simpler code:

```
a=[3,2,2,3]
a.pop(a[3])
```

What it means is:

- `a[3]` - take third element of the list, it's 3 (remember this is 0-indexed)
- so in this situation `a.pop(a[3])` happens to be the same as `a.pop(3)`
- so it removes the third element

Now your error happens because you do `a.pop(a[2])` which is again a 3, and the list is too short.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out your usage error.

Even easier, just take the slice of list that you want:

```
a = sorted(a)[:-2]
```

This sorts the list, strips off the last two entries, and assigns the result back to `a`.

```
>>> a = [5, 8, 3, 2]
>>> a = sorted(a)[:-2]
>>> a
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the pop function twice without parametrs like this:

```
a.pop()
a.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the last elements you dont need to pass a parameter to pop. Just call a.pop() twice.

The problem rest in that you are not passing the index but the value of the array in the determinate position. When you do pop of a[3] the value is 3 and that index no longer exist because the array size is 3 and the last index is 2.